# Apk file generated from Android Studio too large

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, material-design, android-appcompat

A simplest Hello World app generated from A.S. is almost 5MB! But in Eclipse it is only about 100KB
and when I create a project, The A.S. use the `android.support:appcompat-v7` by default. Here is build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "test.elva.testapp"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
}
```

In Eclipse, if you set minSdkVersion up to 14, the project doesn't use appcompat-v7 library,and the class is extended to `Activity`,not `AppCompatActivity` in A.S.

[Apk detail pic.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NZeW7.png)

Comment: First, you don't actually ask a question. I'm assuming you want to know "Why?" and/or "how to reduce the size?" - second, you don't provide any information about how you have Eclipse setup. Your issue may be with `compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])` or `minifyEnabled false` for example

Comment: Ok,hmm..I just start to learn Adnroid,anything stupid please please forgive me

Answer (score 3):

You can't compare the dimension since you are including different libraries.
In Android Studio you are including the appcompat library with has code and resources, and has other dependencies like `support-v4` library.

You can customize your `build.gradle` script.

For example you can remove the `AppCompat` library, commenting on removing the line from the `dependencies` block

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    //compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
}
```

AS is using the `AppCompatActivity` as standard.
Yes it is true. There are many reasons for that, mainly the backport of material design under api 21.
Without the appcompat, you can't use view like as the **Toolbar** or views provided by the **Design support library**.

You can find official info here:

- [AppCompat Library](http://android-developers.blogspot.it/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html)
- [AppCompat 22.1](http://android-developers.blogspot.it/2015/04/android-support-library-221.html)
- [Design Library](http://android-developers.blogspot.it/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html)
- [AppCompat 23.1](http://android-developers.blogspot.it/2015/10/android-support-library-231.html)

You can also remove the unused resources using:

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
```

More [info here](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/resource-shrinking).